# Live version of Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, live-usb, live-cd, livedvd, text-mode

I know that Ubuntu Desktop comes with a Live mode, but unfortunately that DVD boots straight to GUI (I'm on a text-only machine).  I haven't seen an option to Try Ubuntu Server.

Is there a live version of Ubuntu Server?  Or at least a live version of Ubuntu minus the GUI?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop DVD boots to GUI if you let it, but if you replace `quite splash` with `text`, it should boot to a terminal prompt.

Comment: @mikewhatever, changing those options just make the cui not be hidden; it is always there underneath, but the defaults of `quiet` and `splash` just keep it hidden under a friendly splash screen until the full gui finishes loading, thus avoiding the "scary" transition from cui to gui for those who have the gui installed.  This really doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @psusi Indeed, thanks for pointing out that cli is always there, and that comments are not answers, ...least we forget.

Comment: @mikewhatever, sorry: I just read that as remove quiet and splash, and did not see the text part.  That actually is a pretty good answer so you should post it as such.

Comment: If it'll let me boot Ubuntu Desktop without a GUI, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as try(without install) option for server editions.

Please refer to a similar question which was asked previously.
[Should a 14.04 server iso operate as a live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634646/should-a-14-04-server-iso-operate-as-a-live-cd)

Answer (score 6):

There is now :D

You can get live server images now.  Here's the link for 18.04, see the server images near the bottom

http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/

For example:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso

-enjoy!

Comment: do you know more about the differences? ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso  vs ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso

Comment: @TiloBunt: The interactive UI installer seems not the same. On the "live" iso, exiting the interactive mode to access the console mode (for sample: automate installation with packer) seems not possible. Classic server ISO (no "live") can be found on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04.1/release/